# ansi-c : assignment makes integer from pointer without cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm trying to learn more about C and I was wondering if anyone could clarify what's going on here. I'm getting a compiler warning: "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast @ msg[msglen+1] = "\0""

```
char *msg = NULL;
int len = 10;
int msglen = 0;

while(<argument>) {

msg = (char *)calloc(len, 1);
strncpy(msg, <some string>, len);
msglen = strlen(msg);
msg[msglen+1] = "\0";
```

Thanks, I appreciate you help!

Comment: You're using `strncpy()`. That's almost certainly [not the best solution](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: `msglen = strlen(msg);` has potential for undefined behaviour, since `strncpy` doesn't usually 0-terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a "\0" is treated as a constant string, and the address to that string is slapped into place when you try to do `msg[len - 1] = "\0"` hence you get the message "converts..."

do this instead `msg[len - 1] = '\0'`

Comment: +1 the answer please, if you think this helped :-) @txcotrader

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assing a pointer to a string literal to a `char`. Change the double quotes `"` for single quotes `'` like this:

```
msg[len - 1] = '\0';
```

Notice that I changed `msglen+1` for `len - 1` which indexes the last allocated character.

Comment: It seems to be initialized to 10 and never changed afterwards. But that would present a problem before that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg = malloc(len + 1);
/* check return value here ... */
memcpy(msg, some_string, len);
msg[len] = 0;
msglen = strlen (msg); /* this is to catch premature NULs */
```